# Javascript not working on asp:Datalist checkbox onchange

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, checkbox

This is a Datalist in my code.

```
<asp:DataList runat="server" ID="dlstate" RepeatColumns="6">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chk" Text='<%#Eval("area_state") %>' OnCheckedChanged="chk_state_SelectedIndexChanged" onchange="return checkconfirm(this);" AutoPostBack="true" />
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

This is the Javascript code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkconfirm(a) {
        if (a.checked == true) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            debugger;
            var box = confirm("Are you sure you want to unselect this state as areas alloted under this state will be lost?");
            if (box == true)
                return true;
            else {
                a.checked = true;
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

The problem is that when this apsx page is rendered in html the `onchange="return checkconfirm(this);"` appears on a span rather than the checkbox. I have tried several ways for confirmation and yet I am not able to put the onchange event on the checkbox.

Comment: try to change `onchange` with `OnClick`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a jQuery listener for this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%= dlstate.ClientID %> input[type='checkbox']").change(function () {
            if (!$(this).prop("checked")) {
                var box = confirm("Are you sure you want to unselect this state as areas alloted under this state will be lost?");
                if (box == true)
                    return true;
                else {
                    $(this).prop("checked", "checked");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```